# VB.NET 2015 - MDI Form starts before Splashscreen ends

Tags: vb.net

I have a splashscreen with a delay set programaticly to a delay from 5000 ms. When I set the Signing property to an mdi-form this mdi-form is displayed above the splashscreen. If I set the Signing  property to a normal form the splashscreen is displayen and after the delay is passed the "normal" form opens. How do I prevend that my mdi-form overules my splashscreen ?
Thanks for any help on this !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), most notably [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use `Formname.Bringtofront`? this codes sets the form always on the top. Try to put this code in `Form_Load` of your splashscreen.